# Python ipaddress.collapse_addresses method not returning all IPv4Network's

Tags: python

Given the below code, why aren't the missing 4 IPs included in the results as /32 networks?

Original list length: 23
Reversed list length: 19

Missing ip's:
151.41.156.144
151.41.156.159
151.41.156.160
151.41.156.163

```
import ipaddress

ips = [
    "151.41.156.144",
    "151.41.156.145",
    "151.41.156.146",
    "151.41.156.147",
    "151.41.156.148",
    "151.41.156.149",
    "151.41.156.150",
    "151.41.156.151",
    "151.41.156.152",
    "151.41.156.153",
    "151.41.156.154",
    "151.41.156.155",
    "151.41.156.156",
    "151.41.156.157",
    "151.41.156.158",
    "151.41.156.159",
    "151.41.156.160",
    "151.41.156.161",
    "151.41.156.162",
    "151.41.156.163",
    "151.41.156.164",
    "151.41.156.165",
    "151.41.156.166"
]

print(f"Original list length: {len(ips)}")

ips_objects = [ipaddress.IPv4Address(_) for _ in ips]
cidrs = list(ipaddress.collapse_addresses(ips_objects))

reverse_ips = []

for i in cidrs:
    host_ips = ipaddress.IPv4Network(i).hosts()
    for j in host_ips:
        reverse_ips.append(str(j))

print(f"Reversed list length: {len(reverse_ips)}")
print("\nMissing ip's:")

for k in ips:
    if k not in reverse_ips:
        print(k)
```

I'm expecting to be able to reverse the output of ipaddress.collapse_addresses (a bunch of IPv4Network objects) using the IPv4Network(IPv4Network).hosts method.  However, it appears that ipaddress.collapse_addresses is not outputting all of the networks that I would expect.

Comment: The question (about a specific issue I was having) was asked and then answered by treuss.  The question was adequate enough for treuss to answer so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IPv4Network.hosts()` will only return the host addresses of an IP-Network, i.e. not the network address (where all host bits are 0), neither the broadcast address (where all host bits are 1). So for a `/30`-network it will only return two hosts while the network actually covers 4 addresses.

This is in line with the common definition of what a host address is.

From the python documentation:

---

**hosts()**

Returns an iterator over the usable hosts in the network. The usable hosts are all the IP addresses that belong to the network, except the network address itself and the network broadcast address.

---

**Illustration**:

```
>>> netw = ipaddress.IPv4Network("10.52.53.240/30")
>>> print(f"The network address is {netw.network_address}")
The network address is 10.52.53.240
>>> print("The host addresses are "+", ".join([str(host) for host in netw.hosts()]))
The host addresses are 10.52.53.241, 10.52.53.242
>>> print(f"The broadcast address is {netw.broadcast_address}")
The broadcast address is 10.52.53.243
```